# How do I control timing of javascript execution in relation to other scripts loading dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I've created a small piece of javascript to target some dynamically loaded HTML from a plugin script (YOTPO Reviews).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.location.hash) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('write-review-wrapper')[0].style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

I'm running into 'x is not defined' type errors and I assume this is because my script is running before the Yotpo widget script has finished loading the HTML I'm selecting?

I know I can execute the script after the DOM has loaded with the window.onload state and this works, however because I've got so many other scripts that are taking time to load in, such as live chat, tracking etc. It's too slow and what I'm trying to achieve becomes somewhat pointless.

The YOTPO script loads in an acceptable time, but how can I get my script to execute just after it's loaded (if that is indeed the issue here)?

Comment: My if statement includes the window.location.hash because I only want my piece of script to execute when there's a # in the URL

Comment: If your script is depending on another script to load first, then perhaps you can use `<script defer src="your_script_name"></script>` in the head tag of your HTML. Use this tag for each of the scripts in the order you need them to be loaded. Is that what you are looking for?